# Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

While creating jsp template using custom tag I get the following error:

> Scripting elements ( <%!, <jsp:declaration, <%=, <jsp:expression, <%, <jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.

My user details tag file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@tag description="Base Template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@tag import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@tag import="com.sample.beans.common.User"%>
<%@tag import="java.util.Map" %>
<%@tag import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<%
   request.setAttribute("userDetails", userDetails);
%>
<%@attribute name="title"%>
<%@attribute name="custom_style" fragment="true"%>
<%@attribute name="body_area" fragment="true" %>
<%@attribute name="custom_script" fragment="true"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>${title}</title>

        <jsp:invoke fragment="custom_style"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <jsp:invoke fragment="body_area"/>
        </div>

        <jsp:invoke fragment="custom_script"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

My user.jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:userdetails title="test">
   <jsp:attribute name="body_area">
      <button id="who">click me</button>
   </jsp:attribute>
   <jsp:attribute name="custom_script">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#who').on('click', function() {
            alert(${requestScope.userdetails.username});
        });
    });
    </script>
   </jsp:attribute>
</t:userdetails>
```

Comment: *are disallowed here.* - **where?**

Comment: Try putting `language="java"` into your `page` declaration.

Comment: @ScaryWombat in user.jsp file.

Comment: @Thomas same error

Comment: The problem might be that `user.jsp` doesn't contain the `<html>` and thus `<script>` etc. are disallowed. Try moving the html and doctype tags out of your template and into the page that will include it.

Comment: @Thomas i have those tags inside userdetails.tag file

Comment: That's what I mean: try moving them. I'm not that familiar with that templating mechanism since we mostly used struts 2 on top of it (and we're moving away from JSPs in general) so I can only guess: the jsp renderer first analyzes `user.jsp` without resolving the template and since the `<html>` is missing there it might complain.